# Main PID: 261452 (code=killed, signal=ABRT) Linux Ubuntu

Tags: server, 20.04, apache2

When I run my project asp.net core on the vps server - I get this error.

sudo systemctl status  employeeservicefile.service

```
● employeeservicefile.service - Running ASP.NET Core on Ubuntu 18.04 Webserver APACHE
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/employeeservicefile.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
  enabled)
 Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: signal) since Sat 2021-09-18 11:46:43 CEST; 4s ago
Process: 261452 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/employee/RealEstate.dll (code=killed, 
 signal=ABRT)   
Main PID: 261452 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
```

When I go to my domain it is showing my project file only not site
how can i solve this problem?

> services file

```
[Unit]
Description=Running ASP.NET Core on Ubuntu 20.04 Webserver APACHE
[Service]
  WorkingDirectory=/var/www/employee/
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/employee/RealEstate.dll
   Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> GNU nano 4.8                                                                                   /etc/apache2/sites-available/employee.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xyz@xyz.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/employee/

<Directory /var/www/employee/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

> systemctl status apache2.servic

active running without error